# Return different type from std::exception::what() other than const char*

Tags: c++11, exception, type-conversion

I read [what-is-the-purpose-of-stdexceptionwhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497601/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdexceptionwhat) and referenced the definition of `std::exception` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099436/inheriting-from-stdexception-ambiguity-in-definitions-of-stdexception)

I need to return an `int` from `std::exception::what()` as it is `virtual` but I can't override by return type.  I rolled my own exception class

```
class BadLengthException : public std::exception
{
private:
    int length;
    const char* to_return;
public:
    BadLengthException() = default;
    BadLengthException(int new_length) : length(new_length) { to_return = new const char(length); }
    ~BadLengthException() = default;
    const char* what() const throw() { return to_return; }

};
```

How would I be able to alter the return type to pure `int` to suit my needs such that

```
try
{
}
catch(BadLengthException bad_length)
{
   std::cout << bad_length.what() <------- Got your int value
}
```

**Edit** I made changes to the code.  Testing shows it provides the correct values.  Can I improve upon what I have done considering I must always return a `const char*`?

```
class BadLengthException : public std::exception
{
private:
    const size_t size = 2;
    char ref_arr[5] = { '1','2','3','4','5' };
    int length;
    char* to_return;
public:
    BadLengthException() = default;
    BadLengthException(int new_length) : length(new_length) 
    { 
        to_return = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        to_return[0] = ref_arr[length - 1];
        to_return[1] = '\0';
    }
    ~BadLengthException() = default;
    const char* what() const throw() override { return to_return; }

};
```

Comment: You don't. Why not just add an additional method? Catchers of your exception can then say `bad_length.length()` or whtaever.

Comment: @GManNickG In this particular problem I'm solving, the expected output is constrained to only `std::exception::what()`

Comment: _I need to use what because I need to use what_ ok

Comment: @manni66 I know right?  Jibberish!  I'm new to C++ and new to rolling my own exception classes.  I realized I don't need an int just something that holds an int to be returned upon `throw`

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this.

If you must do this:

```
struct custom_error:std::exception {
  const char* what() const throw() override final { return str.c_str(); }
  explicit custom_error(std::string s):str(std::move(s)) {}
  explicit custom_error(int x):custom_error(std::to_string(x)) {}
private:
  std::string str;
};
```

now we store and return a serialized description of your `int` in a buffer, and return a pointer into it on request.

To convert back:

```
int main() {
  try {
    throw custom_error(34);
  } catch ( std::exception const& ex ) {
    std::stringstream ss(ex.what());
    int x;
    if (ss >> x) {
      std::cout << "X is " << x << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc37c9586e0a6915).